Document Metadata will not update
SharePoint 2019...what fun.
Weirdest thing is happening with a handful of documents. We have a column called "Classification". It is a managed metadata column. It has 5 terms that can be selected. These are all govt classification terms.
This has always been the way throughout the various incarnations of SharePoint that we have worked with in this place.
Somehow, a few documents have "Classification" set to a term that exists in our term store, but not in the "classification" term set.

"Agenda" is not a selectable term in this column

These are our selectable terms.
If I delete Agenda from the property for this document, it will disappear and allow me to select one of the correct terms.
However, as soon as I click off the property, the term resets to Agenda.
Things I have tried so far:

Editing the property in the property pane

Editing the property in Quick Edit

Reverting to SharePoint classic and editing the property

Opening the document and editing the property within the document properties

Migrating the document to another library using Sharegate and forcing a valid term into the column as part of the migration (this initially seemed to work, but as soon as I then tried to update the property again, it reverted back to "Agenda")


Thoroughly confused by this, feels like perhaps there's some hard coded term in the document that refuses to be overwritten, but no idea how this is the case.
Any help appreciated
